ideas to reduce association tables while building a data warehouse
I'm trying to create a data warehouse for my BI project. Initially I have a raw database that contains 100 data tables, most of them are association tables. My goal is to create normalized dimensional modelling in order to centralize my data the most possible but it seems impossible.
Here is an example use case : imagine having a firmware, device and many more  tables with many to many relationship with a user table, this way association tables would be created automatically to save every device or firmware created by users ,I want to get rid of these association tables in order to create more centralized dimension/fact tables ,is there any proposition and a solution for this specific use case?

The first question you need to ask yourself is what is/are your fact table(s). In other word, what are the events you want to report on?
Maybe the action of installing a firmware on a device is your event.
You would then a fact table for installs. Users, devices and firmwares would be modeled in dimensions.
Your tables could be

FACT_INSTALL
DIM_TIME
DIM_USER
DIM_FIRMWARE
DIM_DEVICE

The fact table would hold the surrogate keys for the dimensions.

Yes i understand ,the example scenario you provided is correct. users, devices and firmwares are indeed dimension tables , but there is more data related to these dimensions in association tables that i need in later analysis / vizualisation. i tried to integrate these tables with the dimensions directly but it would create a huge data redundancy ,so my specific question here : how could i use the data located in associaton tables without affecting my data warehouse quality?
what are the approaches i could use reduce the number of association tables or deal with it differently

i searched about a concept bridge tables in data warehousing but i thought it would change nothing in my case as my goal is to reduce the number of bridge tables in my data warehousing model to increase query performance and so on ..
thanks for your contribution

We need to see some examples of your association tables. But some part of it might find its place in the fact table.
